# How can we make any object flow on table or other object in apple watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacegroup

Simply like the text input controller

I tried put table inside a group with buttons inside a group below it, thought the group could scroll like a scrollView but failed.

[well i can't send image yet...]

so any help here?

Comment: You might want to use -(void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex instead

Comment: @Horst thanks, but I am trying to make two buttons always flow on the bottom of the screen and a scrollable table on the background

Comment: You can link images if you put them online and we can edit to include it in the post.